# Memory decline when use drools stream mode

Tags: memory, drools, complex-event-processing

I use Drools 6.2.Final Fusion CEP, and i have set event @expires (1d), but i found that the memery have been declining few days later. Every day the total of event data is not much.I doubt the event in working memery after the expiration is not clear.so i want to confirm something:

1.Fusion CEP stream mode Stateful session is must dispose() after fireAllRules()? In my code the ksession will only create once at the init method, and then use it insert an event and fire all rules, but i never use the dispose() method after fire. I'm worried about is not that I did not use the method that caused the event has been kept in memory.

2.The event after the expiration will automatically removed from memory? I fear that the event is not properly cleared, resulting in memory has been declining.

```
@org.kie.api.definition.type.Role(org.kie.api.definition.type.Role.Type.EVENT)
@org.kie.api.definition.type.TypeSafe(true)
@org.kie.api.definition.type.Timestamp("beginTime")
@org.kie.api.definition.type.Expires("1d")
public class Event{
    private Long beginTime;

    // ...other fields, set and get method..
}
```

--

```
poublic void initKsession()throws Exception{
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieBaseConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieBaseConfiguration();
    config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
    ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId(groupId, artifactId, version);
    KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
    KieScanner kScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kContainer);    
    kSession = kContainer.newKieSession(kessionName);
    kScanner.start(10000L);
}
```

--

```
public Result processRules(Event event) {
    // ....
    try {
        kSession.insert(event);
        kSession.fireAllRules();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("fail",e);
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to judge what you are doing from your sketchy remarks. What do you mean by "after fire"? Or by "use accumulate function"? Or "memory have beed down"? - Are you sure it is events that cause OoM? Did you attach a listener keeping track of insertions and deletions, maintaining the balance?

Comment: Sorry,i fixed the description.What i want to ask is that the event in workingMemery is not automatically removed reasons,and how to keep the balance of memory.Thx for your help @laune

Comment: Don't call `dispose` on a StatefulKieSession unless after you have terminated the use of this session - it is the very final clean-up. - Use a listener to learn how your event facts are entered and deleted and how their number increases. Then, knowing this, it is time to discuss how to discard obsolete/outdated events.

Comment: Yeah,is there any drools method/api can remove obsolete event batch?@laune

Comment: There is retract, and you'll have to implement the "obsolete" test.

Answer (score 1):

After the test I found why the event has not been removed correctly.I need to declare @expires in a rule like this:

```
declare Event
    @role(event)
    @timestamp(beginTime)
    @expires(2m)
end
```

And the comment does not take effect where i add above the class Event.

```
@org.kie.api.definition.type.Timestamp("beginTime")
@org.kie.api.definition.type.Expires("1d")
public class Event{....}
```